# EXCEL - INDEX/VLOOKUP for multiple columns in different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a need to verify discrepancies in Id's between different sheets for employees. However the results are not fruitful with the formula's I have tried.

Sheet1

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| Skyler | 1 |
| Walter | 3 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Roman | 4 |

Sheet2

| Name | Id |
| --- | --- |
| Roman | 2 |
| Skyler | 3 |
| Peter | 4 |
| Walter | 1 |

I have tried using below formula in a different column to filter discrepancies, but since the order of employees is not same, its not working as expected.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))=Sheet2!B2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=XLOOKUP(D2:D5,A2:A5,B2:B5,,0)=E2:E5
```

[image]